# Can Javascript toggle frameborders?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use JS to toggle a frame's frameborder attribute. Here is my test case:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function off() {
      var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
      var f2 = document.getElementById("f2");
      alert ("before, frame f1 had frameBorder=" + f1.frameBorder);
      f1.frameBorder = "0";
      alert ("after, frame f1 has frameBorder=" + f1.frameBorder);
      alert ("before, frame f2 had frameBorder=" + f2.frameBorder);
      f2.frameBorder = "0";
      alert ("after, frame f2 has frameBorder=" + f2.frameBorder);
    }
  </script>
  </head>

  <frameset cols="50%, 50%" name="fs">
    <frame frameborder="1" src="http://bikeshed.com" id="f1" name="f1" />
    <frame frameborder="1" src="http://bikeshed.com" id="f2" name="f2" />
  </frameset>
</html>
```

I load this up in Firefox, open up Firebug, and type "off()" into the console. It runs my function, which reports that both frameborders had been set to "1" and are now set to "0" .. however, the frame border fails to disappear.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, how?

Comment: While you can change the frameborder attribute, neither Safari nor FF re-renders the page, so you won't notice the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using iframes instead of frames seems to work. You'll have to work on the CSS a bit to complete the illusion of a frameset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Frame Test</title>
  <script language="javascript">
    var off = function () {
      document.getElementById('frame1').style.borderWidth = 0;
      alert('off');
    }
  </script>


</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%" cols="2">
<tr>
<td><iframe id="frame1" src="http://www.google.com" style="margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%"></iframe></td>
<td><iframe id="frame2" src="http://www.google.com" style="margin: 0; width: 100%;  height: 100%"></iframe></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in IE8. Internet Explorer treats the frameborder as a separate border to the CSS border! (I'm currently having the issue that I cannot clear the frameborder in IE8 using script - I suspect that IE8 is simply not updating the page (as hinted in the comment at top) as the attribute appears to be set OK?!)

Answer (score 1):

For some attributes, you need to use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute).  Try

```
f1.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
```

Comment: I think it should be `frameBorder` with a capital B. But in fact either work these days on FF 3.6 when applied to iframes, as suggested by @Patrick above.

Comment: @w3d: "frameborder" is more correct, as the attribute name is all lowercase. You might be thinking of camel case used when accessing CSS properties, which frameborder isn't, as a replacement for the dashes in CSS property names. In Firefox, [`setAttribute` converts the attribute name to lower case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute#Notes), which is why either works. Some other browsers seem to do the same, though it isn't standard behavior so shouldn't be relied on. Patrick isn't using the frameborder attribute, so I'm not sure what you mean by your second sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding `setAttribute`, yes "frameborder" (all lowercase) would seem to be more correct and makes more sense. My confusion, however, came about because the corresponding JavaScript property is `frameBorder`, so if using object dot notation to set the property/attribute you must use `iframeObj.frameBorder = 0` in order to remove the frameborder attribute. This was further confused by IE's previous(?) inability to distinguish between properties and attributes and the fact that `setAttribute('frameborder',0)` does not work in IE8.

Comment: @otis In referring to Patrick's post, I was really just referring to his use of iframes. And I've been dealing with iframes recently, not frames per se.